# Menu settings does not change menu

Tags: 7

I have created a new menu called `new-menu`.  I go to Admin > Structure > Menus > Settings

And I choose "New Menu"  for the "Source for the Main links" option.

However, on my site, it still shows the Main Menu links (instead of New Menu links).

What am I missing?

**Note:** I am running a custom "Drupal core" from my university, and I've never worked with Vanilla Drupal, so I'm not sure if something is missing that should be there.

Comment: What theme are you running? How are you printing your menu in your page.tpl?

Comment: I'm running Zen theme, but using a custom core from my university (which I mention because it's been the answer to other issues I've had like this)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the menu under Structure > Blocks. Find the Main Menu block that is active and click its "Configure" link. The third option is Menu... change this to dropdown to your new-menu.

Comment: I don't have a "Main Menu" block.  I have a "Navigation" block, which does not list the "main-menu" listed in it.